# How to Link to a file in ASP.NET MVC 4 using Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm making a web app using ASP.NET MVC 4. 
It lets people upload files. 
I want to list all the files from a user with a link to open/download each file. 
 
I have the virtual path to each file (e.g. :`~/Folder/file.txt`), how can I generate the link with razor? 
I tried with `@Href` but it doesn't render anything, same thing with `@Url.Content`. 
I tried also without using razor but I don't think it's a good way... 
Your help would be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: you are saving files in a folder???

Comment: @Exception, where do you usually save yours? :)

Comment: @AndreiV...database....

Comment: Are you referencing the file hardcoded in your project?

Comment: @Exception, You save files to a database!?!?! Well that's expensive... Why not something like Azure Storage? Of just a directory?

Comment: @Exception, what's the largest file you ever saved in a database? What DBMS do you usually use?

Comment: if you are referencing files from your folder then you are using correct helper i.e url.content or @href...just check path..

Comment: @RalphJansen..due to security reasons we save files in database..

Comment: Could you post your code in order to see how the links get generated?

Comment: @RalphJansen what do you mean by hardcoded? I save the path in database and I'd like to render it using razor

Comment: Just Post code plz....

Comment: Here it is:
`@foreach (var s in Model)
{
   <tr>
       <td>@s.Id.ToString()</td>
       <td>@s.Title</td>
       <td><a href="@Href(s.FilePath)">link</a></td>
   </tr>
}`

Comment: then when you are clicking on anchor tag file is not opening???

Comment: Please post the generated HTML also.

Comment: Mark me with the "NOOB" label... I emptied my db which had null values for FilePath, I rewrited the few lines above with a condition for null value and now it works fine!... I'll post the answer... Sorry for that, I don't really know what was wrong before and thank you for your time!

Comment: @Exception Why is filesystem a security problem? If you save files to the database and you have access to it is the same if you have access to the directory? If you close both, the security is the same. Or you have access or you haven't. There isn't something like maybe access...

Comment: @RalphJansen...besides security issues there is problem of saving in folder like if someday that folder or complete directory gets corrupted or deleted accidentally..

Comment: @Exception your db may be corrupted or deleted as well, that's why backup exists, and you can backup folders too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why @Href didn't work but it's the way to do it! 
Here is a sample code:

```
@foreach (var s in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@s.Id.ToString()</td>
        <td>@s.Title</td>
        <td>
            @if (s.FilePath!= null && s.FilePath!= "")
            {
                <a href="@Href(s.FilePath)">link</a>
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```